# nginx: how to redirect to https while still serving one directory via http?

Tags: http, nginx, https, lets-encrypt, nginx-location

I want to prevent people from using my site via http and force them to use a secure connection. My https certificate is issued by letsencrypt (via the webroot option), which means they connect via http where I serve the static content from `/.well-known/acme-challenge/`. All other requests should be redirected to use https. Following the relevant part of my nginx.conf

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name example.com www.example.com admin.example.com;
    location /.well-known/acme-challenge {
        root /app;
        access_log on;
        try_files $uri $uri/ =418;
    }

    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}
```

This https upgrade works fine and all users get an https connection as intended. The Problem is, that nginx upgrades EVERY request made, even those from letsencrypt, which cause letsencrypt to fail - it doesn't even try to serve the file (the file exists!).

How can I ensure that if a request comes via http to `example.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/[HASH]` it will serve the file if found or return a 418 error while simultaneously upgrading all other requests to https which dont start with `/.well-known/acme-challenge`? Thanks for any suggestions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `return 301` is in server scope, which is not what you want. Place the `return` inside a default location:

```
location / {
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}
```

Comment: It must have been late at night, as this is what I had "originally" but something didn't work so I changed it based on resources I found. Now awake, this obviously works as expected! thanks for showing me the light out of the tunnel ;)